# Is it possible to have a nav tags ul tags use the nav tags grid?

Tags: css, grid

The title is a bit confusing. So here is some code

HTML

```
<nav class="container">
  <img src="img/Reservia.svg" alt="Reservia Logo" class="logo" />
  <ul class="nav">
    <li class="link1">
      <a href="#accommodations">Accommodations</a>
    </li>
    <li class="link2"><a href="#activities">Activities</a></li>
    <li class="link3"><a href="#signUp" id="signUp">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is what I have of the CSS

```
nav {
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
height: 120px;
width: 425px;}
```

I am wondering if it is possible to have the logo in one fr and the li tags in each of the remaining frs? This is also for a mobile sized screen.

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy way to do it. Basically you delete the ul container and asign grid-column and row of the logo to 1/2 ,then all the others would be automatically set in the other containers. The reason you have to delete the ul container is that since it's a container you can't cover all the grid areas but only one or more adjacent columns/rows.
CSS:

```
<style>

        nav { 
            display: grid;
            grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
            height: 120px;
            width: 425px;
            }
        nav img{
            grid-column: 1/2;
            grid-row:1/2;
        }
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<nav class="container">
  <img src="img/Reservia.svg" alt="Reservia Logo" class="logo" />
    <li class="link1">
      <a href="#accommodations">Accommodations</a>
    </li>
    <li class="link2"><a href="#activities">Activities</a></li>
    <li class="link3"><a href="#signUp" id="signUp">Sign Up</a></li>
</nav>
```